# "Unable to forget Hot Spot" - Can't disconnect from it either

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, connection-issues

I am running stock kitkat (4.4.4). There are some hotspots my phone will connect to whenever I am near. If I try to disconnect from it, I get an error message that says:

`Unable to forget Hot Spot` (sic).

My only options are to disable WiFi or keep connected.

If I am not near that hotspot, *it won't even show up on the list of memorized hotspots*.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

These are probably hotspots set up by your carrier, designed to reduce load on their 3G/4G network by offloading some of it to WiFi. You would not be able to prevent using these unless you turn off WiFi (why is that a problem for you?) or root / use a custom firmware.

Comment: That seems... Presumptuous...